# Set and delete or just overwrite?

Tags: redis

I have keys in Redis that after being read once are no longer needed. Should I delete them or just let them sit in the database until I need the key again?
I guess the question is which costs more: unneeded data sitting in the database, or a delete operation?

The set command overwrites if string data already exists at the key specified. So, in a way there is a delete and write command, I could use a get and delete command. 
Or I could just call delete after getting a key. My question is should I, or just let the key sit there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only dealing with one key at a time, then overwriting ([set](https://redis.io/commands/set)) versus deleting ([del](https://redis.io/commands/del)) both only have a time complexity of O(1) as per the Redis documentation. I'm personally a fan of deleting an entry as soon as I'm finished with it since it is low cost and keeps the storage at a minimum. That being said, both time complexities are low, so overwriting shouldn't be an issue either :)

Comment: It is the combination of get and del that I am talking about. I guess I need to determine which is more appropriate for my data set.